# How to detect DOM nodes insertion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onchange

I need to detect DOM changes (especially when adding DOM elements). 

So that a method may be called in Chrome, Firefox, IE9+

Let's assume we have a button to add li dynamically as follows:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="Add Item"> 
<ul/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("<li />").html("item").appendTo("ul");
    })
</script>
```

I need something like that to detect li additions for example:

```
onDomChange(function(){ 
    alert("DOM changed !");
});
```

I've implemented this solution: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Lcybj/

but  it only works on Chrome.

**How to achieve a solution to work on 3 browsers ?**

Comment: I've found many solutions, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcybj/ .
This only works for one or two browsers.

Answer (score 1):

There are some events, but i don't think they are supported by all browsers. Take a look a this (Row Mutation): [WIKI DOM EVENTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Common.2FW3C_events)